# Loading large remote SVG files without React native becoming unresponsive

Tags: javascript, react-native, svg

I have been trying to load remote SVGs using SvgUri from the react-native-svg package which works well with smaller SVG files but I have some very large SVG files that need to be loaded which causes the app to become unresponsive. I assume this is due the conversion of the large SVG file blocking react native's single JS thread.Are there any alternative packages that could be used to work around this or that use some form of device multithreading like the react-native-reanimated package?

I've tried using the onLoad function in the SvgUri component but that is only useful for displaying an alernative loading SVG while the app is unresponsive.

```
const SVGLoader: React.FC<SVGLoaderProps> = ({uri, height, width}) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  function handleOnLoad() {
    console.log('loaded');
    setLoading(false);
  }

  return (
    <View>
      {loading === true ? <LoadingIcon /> : null}
      <SvgUri
        onLoad={() => handleOnLoad()}
        width={width}
        height={height}
        uri={uri}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```